# Provider cannot be found on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: sql, oracle, vba, 64-bit, connection-string

I am trying to run our very old application on Windows 7 64 bit. In this application we use our do template in which there are a Visual Basic scripts. I have a problem with database provider. This is my string connection:

```
  buildConnectString = _
    "Provider=MSADORA.1" + _
    ";Password=""" + pPassword + _
    """;User ID=" + pUser + _
    ";Data Source=" + pDB + ";"
```

I receive this error:

> Run-time error 3706. Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly
>   installed.

Is there any possibility to run it on 64-bit operating system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the Oracle provider (there are 32bit and 64bit versions), then use `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle`

[BTW, its `MSDAORA.1`. MSDAORA is only available for **x86/32bit**, there is **no 64 bit** driver]

Microsoft are no longer supporting MSDAORA, and instead recommended you use the Oracle drivers.

Download page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html

Comment: I've installed it, bu I have still the same error. Maybe it is because I have Oracle 6i installed on my machine.

Comment: I've installed it on clean machine. Now I have this error: "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the provider name for the MS provider is MSD***A***ORA. So it seems you are missing the A in your connect string.